# Simple, IO concerning vertex shader in webGL

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

So, I'm trying to make sense of some code before I copy and paste it into my application.  In openGL I'm seeing some variables typed as in and out.  I see no such thing in the following code snippet.  From what I understand, the vertex shader "magically" gets the input for the "in" typed variables via the program, which incidentally can have a fragment and vertex shader attached to it(the program).  Heres the code:

```
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec2 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aPlotPosition;

varying vec2 vPosition;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0, 1.0);
    vPosition = aPlotPosition;
}
</script>
```

So, my question is, by attaching an appropriate program here, aVertexPosition and aPlotPosition will both be properly initialized and furthermore, vPosition could be used somewhere else in my app, namely the fragment shader?

Comment: addendum:  In the GPU pipeline, I've read: vertex shader -> fragment shader(omitting another shader I dont care about atm).  In the example I'm studying, vPosition is in fact declared in the fragment shader.  Basically, I'm confused about what is happening behind the scenes.  To me, there seems to be a for loop missing looping through the pixels.  It would seem that the GPU is taking care of that by its very nature.

Comment: Further addendum:  It would seem the vertex shader automagically loops through the vertices while the fragment shader loops through the pixels.  Again, the crux of my question is; Is this true?  The GPU is a black box to me right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try and explain how the GPU pipeline I/O works:

Each Vertex has a set of attributes associated with it. Given your example code:

attribute vec2 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aPlotPosition;

You are saying that each vertex has a 2D vertex position and plot position. If you added:

attribute vec3 vNormal;

Then every vertex would also have a normal. You could think of these as vertex "properties".

You must tell the GPU where to fetch the values for each of these attributes.

Each vertex attribute is assigned an attribute array index when the shader is compiled. You must enable each attribute array index that your shader requires

```
enableVertexAttribArray(int attributeIndex);
```

Once you've enabled it, you want to bind the attribute array to a vertex buffer.

```
bindBuffer(ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
```

You now describe how to fetch the attribute with this call:

```
vertexAttribPointer(int attributeIndex, int count, int type, bool normalized, int stride, int offset);
```

Given your example code:

```
vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, FLOAT, false, 16, 0); // vertex position
vertexAttribPointer(1, 2, FLOAT, false, 16, 8); // plot position
```

16 or the stride is the number of bytes between each vertex. Each vertex consists of 4 floats and each float is 4 bytes wide. The offset is where the attribute starts within a vertex. The vertex position is at the 0th byte of the vertex and plot position is at the 8th.

You can think of these as describing how to index into an array. The Nth vertex:

```
aVertexPosition.x = BUFFER[offset + N * stride + sizeof(FLOAT) * 0];
aVertexPosition.y = BUFFER[offset + N * stride + sizeof(FLOAT) * 1];
```

Vertex attributes are fetched automatically for you by the GPU and filled in before your vertex shader function is executed. Yes your vertex shader main is called once for every single vertex you draw.

The output of the vertex shader stage are the 'varying' variables. They are 'varying' because they are interpolated across the surface of the primitive (triangle) between vertices. You write the values out for each vertex but when the triangle is rasterized into fragments, each fragment gets the interpolated value of each varying variable. The fragment shader gets run for every fragment (pixel) that is "covered" by the draw call. If you draw a small triangle that covers a 4x4 patch of pixels then the fragment shader is executed 16 times.

Concisely:

```
Vertex Shader Inputs: Vertex Attributes & Uniform values (not covered)
Vertex Shader Outputs: Varying Values at each vertex
Fragment Shader Inputs: Varying Values for a given fragment (pixel)
Fragment Shader Outputs: Color & Depth values which are stored in the color and depth buffer.

Vertex Shader is run for every vertex in the draw call.
Fragment shader is run for every "covered" or "lit" fragment (pixel) in the draw call.
```

Comment: Yeah, sounds about right.  Thanks a lot!  The "Concisely" is just about what I was looking for at this point.  Now, it's on to really using this nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

In other, newer versions of OpenGL, which have more shader stages than just vertex and fragment, `in` and `out` are used instead of `attribute` and `varying`.

- `attribute` corresponds to `in` for a vertex shader.
- `varying` corresponds to `out` for a vertex shader.
- `varying` corresponds to `in` for a fragment shader.

(I haven't actually used `in` and `out`, so this description may be inaccurate. Please feel free to improve my answer by editing. I don't know how `uniform`s fit in.)

Comment: Basically, what you have here was dawning on me when I posed the question.  The in and out types strike me as existing at a lower lever than the implementation of webGL.  Although, I'm not sure about this, attribute and varying also have an implicit meaning.  varying for example, given two vertices, will encapsulate whatever generic data you decide to shove into it between the two vertices.  Forgive the wording there.